# Can someone help me resolve this problem? Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt

Tags: npm, ant, gruntjs, sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

I am learning hybris and I started using smartedit. The problem is that when I run `ant clean all` or `ant updatesystem` I get this error.

```
Running grunt default
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.3.2)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

https://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

**What have I done till now:**

I have grunt-cli installed globally, and grunt installed locally. Also, I run `npm install`.

Here is my packege.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": "desc"
}
```

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

};
```

I tried a bunch of ways to resolve this problem but nothing seemed to work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Hello, have you run `ant npminstall` before the `ant clean all` ? Can you precise the SAP commerce version you're using ? Thanks.